# Взятие списка (или массива) объектов из БД одним запросом

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Стоит примерно такая задача: нужно подгрузить из БД несколько элементов. Я это представляю примерно следующим образом:

```
public async Task<ResponseType> GetSomeData (List<string> Ids)
{
    List<User> users = DbContext.Users.Where(u=>u.Id == IdFromListIds).ToList();

    // Дальнейшая работа
}
```

Вопрос в том, можно ли эту задачу выполнить за один запрос, а не создавать цикл и запрашивать каждого пользователя отдельно?

Comment: `.Where(u => Ids.Contains(u.Id))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо пользователю @EvgeniyZ за ответ в комментариях. Ниже продублирую его ответ:

```
public async Task<ResponseType> GetSomeData (List<string> Ids)
{
    List<User> users = DbContext.Users.Where(u => Ids.Contains(u.Id)).ToList();

    // Дальнейшая работа
}
```